# iframe-embedded GWT App throws Exception in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, gwt, iframe

we have to embed our GWT-Application in our customeres website. The application consists basically of 4-5 forms that have to be filled and you click continue after you have completed each form. The server-part of the application writes properties for those filled in values.

The app works flawlessly in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer without being embedded. It also works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox when it is embedded using an iframe or the embed-tag. But in Internet Explorer it throws the following exception when clicking the first continue button - hence, writing the first values:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

I mean, i understand the exception but I just can't seem to figure out where it could come from under the previously described circumstances. Since it works without being embedded I suppose it has to do something with the iframe or the embed-tag.
I already tried different doctypes for the containing website because I read that IE inherits doctypes to embedded Websites and / or the doctypes of the two pages have to match. I also tried different values for the sandbox-attribute of the iframe-tag. But after allowing everything it just threw the exception again.

I'm not talking about hosted mode here. The exception appears in the debugging console (F12).

tl:dr: App works perfectly without being embedded. App throws exception in IE after it has been embedded but still works perfectly in FF and Chrome.

Has anyone experienced similar problems with embedding GWT-Applications in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Can you try to log what happens using GWT logging or GWT-log framework?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? There are know problems with in iFrames embedded applications in IE 9 and 10: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/753567/ie9-cannot-enter-text-into-textbox